# Video, Music and Photo lenses show no results

Tags: unity-dash, 16.04, lenses

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 after a botched upgrade from 14.04. When I first logged in my music, videos and photos were in the old installation's home directory of different user name.

After moving them to their respective places in the new home directory the dash lenses report that there is no music, videos or photos available on this computer.

How can I manually update the dash lenses to find my videos, music and photos?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-scope-home
```

and

```
sudo unity --replace & disown
```

did the trick.